# fetch property values using get and set method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to test a function in javascript which uses the get and set methods to fetch values from the property. How do i define the object with the get and set methods so that when the function is called it will be able to get the property values using get and set a new values using set.
I am defining the object as below:

```
var items = {'item.isActive': false};
Object.defineProperty(items, 'item.isActive', {
    get: function() { return items['item.isActive'];},
    set: function(newVal) {
        items['item.isActive'] = newVal;
        }
   });
```

With this when i try to fetch using

```
items.get('item.isActive')
```

I get the error as

```
items.get is not a function
```

Any idea on how to define the items object for the get to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var items = {
    'item.isActive': false,
    get: function() { return this['item.isActive'];},
    set: function(newVal) {
      this['item.isActive'] = newVal;
    }
};

console.log(items.get('item.isActive'));
```

Comment: This is not the same functionality that the original post is trying to achieve.  Getters and setters are part of es5 and you attach them to an object property.

Comment: Kai, this does not produce the "not a function" error but the it gives me the string value 'item.isActive' instead of value 'false'.

Comment: This produces the value `false` when I run it.

Comment: It works when i access directly after defining. However after passing the object to the function where the actual value is set and then trying to access is giving me back the string. This is the code in the called function:                       var isActive = items.get('item.isActive');
                    items.set('item.isActive', !isActive);

Comment: It sounds like you want to pass the get and set functions a parameter that specifies which property you're getting or setting. Maybe rewrite it to do that? Example [here](http://jsbin.com/pojiqidoqi/edit?js,console).

Answer (score 0):

You do not actually call the getter and setter functions directly. They are invoked when you access members of your object.

You would access your property like this: `items['item.isActive']`. However, in your code, you have a bug where invoking the getter will call itself, causing a Maximum call stack size exceeded.

EDIT:

Most likely what you want is:

```
var items = {'_item.isActive': false};
Object.defineProperty(items, 'item.isActive', {
  get: function() { return this['_item.isActive'];},
  set: function(newVal) {
    items['_item.isActive'] = newVal;
  }
});

console.log( items['item.isActive'] );
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I changed according to this. But i need to be able to get the value using the get method e.g. items.get('item.isActive) as this code is already written and i am writing a test for it. Similarly set a new value using set(key, val) method. Still getting the "not a function" error though.

Comment: If you do need to use `items.get`, then @Kai's answer is correct. However, the code you posted is for using the ES5 getters and setters, which are automatically invoked when trying to access a property.